# Sign of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix is ​preserved in connected domains

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis

Suppose we have a continuous map between subsets of Euclidean spaces such that the domain is connected. Why is the sign of the Jacobian matrix determinant preserved in this domain?

Note: I am asking this question because for problems involving orientability it is common for this argument to be used. An example of this is taking an atlas with only two cards whose intersection of domains is connected...

Comment: If $f(x) = (x_1, (x_1-x_2)^2)$ then the Jacobian changes sign on a connected domain. Perhaps there are some missing assumptions?

Comment: For a homeomorphism do you think it is possible to guarantee the above situation?

Answer (score 2):

What you have stated is not true. Consider $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ given by
$$
(x, y) \mapsto (x, x\arctan(y))
$$
then
$$
J = \left(
\begin{split}
&\ \ \ \ \ \ 1 &0 \\
&\arctan(y) \ \  &\frac{x}{1 + y^2}
\end{split}
\right),
$$
and this has negative determinant for $x < 0$, positive for $x > 0$. If we require, however, that $f$ is continuously differentiable and locally invertible, which is satisfied in your example, then the determinant is always non-zero. Hence we will have a well defined map
$$
s : D \subseteq \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb Z_2
$$
by taking $s$ to be the sign of the Jacobian determinant. This is continuous as $f$ is continuously differentiable, the determinant map is continuous and the map $x \mapsto 1 / x$ is continuous away from $0$. Hence we have a continuous map from a connected set to a space with a discrete topology, so must be constant.

Comment: for OP: an alternative way to argue the last part is that the image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected (this is just a generalization of the intermediate value theorem). Now if a subset of $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is connected, then it lies in $(0,\infty)$ or in $(-\infty,0)$.